# robovm binding admob iOS libgdx

Tags: ios, libgdx, admob, robovm

I'm trying to set up my admob ads in my iOS libgdx project but i can't see no ads on iOS emulator I'm using the files from here https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings 
and they are the latest i know there is 7.0.0 admob iOS sdks but the binding are for lower version that suppose to work... or not?

any idea?

or i might shall use different adnetwork?

`<Google:HTML> You are currently using version 6.12.2 of the SDK, which doesn't officially support iOS 8. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent sdk version, 7.0.0, to get iOS 8 support, including a fix for smart banner rendering in landscape mode. The latest SDK can be downloaded from http://goo.gl/iGzfsP. A full list of release notes is available at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/rel-notes.
2015-03-22 10:41:59.822 IOSLauncher[12856:751391] [debug] com.funkymonkey.game.IOSLauncher: didReceiveAd
2015-03-22 10:42:30.217 IOSLauncher[12856:751391] [debug] com.funkymonkey.game.IOSLauncher: didReceiveAd`

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem too. First I downloaded the newest iOS sdk for google mobile ads. Then I made a static library in Xcode. Then created my own bindings.